# Which events are the most intensive?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Which events are the most resource intensive to have attached? Is a `mouseover` "worst" than a `click`? Are there any events that are known to be really harsh on the browser? I have my sights on IE7 mainly, as we are seeing performance issues there. We use event delegation where we can.

Or, how can I profile events which are actually running to determine which have the greatest impact on performance at runtime?

I'm interested in the events themselves, please don't tell me I need to go look into what my functions are doing in those events. Problems may exist there, but that's not my question.

Comment: Best to ask **one** question per question here on Stack Overflow. Your question about which events are most resource-heavy and how to profile are distinct questions.

Comment: I have not noticed events themselves being a problem. Check that you are cacheing results of your selectors and ... i know you dont want to here this but your functions that happen when the event fires

Comment: @T.J - And yet related, since I can answer my first question myself given the answer to my second question. Perhaps you should ponder the question a little more before making judgements.

Comment: @aepheus: then why ask the first if you only need the second answered? TJ is just offering you advice on asking questions, he's not making judgements. Side note, all three answers posted so far appear to be confusing *mouseover* with *mousemove*.  The former fires only once per element the mouse moves over.

Comment: @AndyE - I ask both because my primary question is the first one, though if no one knew the answer to that, but could tell me how I could find the answer myself I would gladly accept that as an answer. It's akin to asking "What's 5+3, or how do you perform addition?" Here I thought stackoverflow was all about getting more generic answer out of questions, so that those answers can be applied to other similar questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, to start with, events that fire more often can be more troublesome. So a mouseover event, which fires "continuously" as the mouse moves over an element, could cause a performance impact more easily than a click event, which can only fire as fast as the user can click.

However, it's the code you put in your handler that will have the real performance impact.

If firing speed is an issue, check out the excellent jQuery throttle/debounce plugin: https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce

Comment: mouseover does not fire continiously. You may mean "mousemove" which is a stupid event

Comment: "However, it's the code you put in your handler that will have the real performance impact." Totally agree the "event" being triggered will have no noticeable effect, what is being done in the handler will. @aepheus needs to check his handlers to optimize his JS

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave fire only once, but mouseover would fire every time you moused over a descendant element, etc. But, point taken.

Comment: Your verbiage suggests the mouseover event is fired continuously for one element, which is demonstrably false. It fires from each (descendant) element, as the event's target will reflect.

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com - So you think in an application using event delegation, that attaching click would have no noticeable difference from mouseover? Doesn't sound right to me...

Comment: @aepheus my point is its not the event that is slowing down the app its the code in the handler, obviously mouseover is going to fire your code more often that click, right? So common sense and intuitiveness comes to play when assigning your event types to your user interactions with your app.

Comment: @aepheus really avoid using a mouseover as long as you do not need to track the mouse position. Even if there is nothing to throw, the host browser will check if there is, which will consume cpu in anyway. Use the events for what they are made for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine a callback's intensity is proportional to how many times it's called.

Events like mouseover or deviceorientation are more demanding than a click or similar 'one time' event.

Answer (score 1):

The more an event have to check (and then throw) the more it consumes i.e. order from the max to the min:

- mousemove throws an event at any move
- mouseover throws an event at each move if pointing on a relevant item
- mouseenter have to watch where is the cursor to then trow something
- mouse click only throws an event when you click…